YouTubeのPremium勧誘ポップアップを消す方法
以下は私が考えた解決策です。
userscriptでCSSを変更する
ポップアップのエレメントのタグ名またはクラス名(e.g. .ytd-popup-container)のstyleのdisplayをnoneに変更する方法です
以下のページでは「クラス名で要素を取得した後そのstyleを変更する方法」は載っていますが、「クラスが指定しているCSS自体を変更する方法」を知りたいです。
document.styleSheetsを使用する方法も載っていますが、CSSファイルが外部にある場合などはcssRulesが読み取れないというエラーが起きます。
How To Change CSS With JavaScript [With Examples] - Alvaro Trigo's Blog
そして気づいたのは、単にポップアップを削除するだけだと画面全体を薄暗くするのは消えないという問題です。
追記
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = 'ytd-popup-container {display: none;} html body[modern-dialog] {--iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity: 0.0;}';
document.head.appendChild(style);

でとりあえず表示は消せますが、「ポップアップそれ自体」は削除できないので、例えば画面をクリックしても一回目は一時停止しません(おそらくポップアップを消す処理に使われるため)。
それと「共有」ポップアップなども表示されないという問題があります。
HTMLを監視しポップアップを削除
手間がかかりますが、MutationObserverでHTMLを監視しポップアップの要素が出現したら削除するようにすれば完全に解決できると思います。

サーバーにある css ファイルを JavaScript で書き換えたいと言ってますか？

@WebSurfer いえ、特定の要素に対してelm.style.display='none'とスタイルを変更できるように、例えば<div class='ytd-popup-container'></div>のように.ytd-popup-containerが指定されている要素すべてのstyleを変更できるように、 .ytd-popup-container が指定するCSSの内容を変更できないかという事です。

以下のページでは「クラス名で要素を取得した後そのstyleを変更する方法」は載っていますが・・・とのことですが、どこに載ってますか？ それではどこがダメなのでしょう？

@WebSurfer 完全に確かめた訳では無いですが、ページをロードした時点では「特定のクラスを持った要素」が存在せず、動的に作られることもあるためです。

「動的に作られる」のは SPA のように JavaScript で作るのだと理解してますが、そうだとすると、質問者さんのやりたいこと「javascriptでCSSの内容を変更」はそもそも不可能ではないのですか？　必ず「動的に作られ」た後で「javascriptでCSSの内容を変更」するようコントロールできればともかく。

.ytd-popup-container は恐らく YouTube に関する CSS ですよね？その辺りも詳しく説明しておいた方が良いと思います。

@cubick そうですね……CSS変更だけでいいと思ってましたがXY問題になってたのでタイトルごと修正します

本当に非表示にできるかどうか(あるいは参照ページと同じものを解説しているのか)不明ですが、こんな記事がありますね。YouTubeプレミアムの勧誘ポップアップを非表示にするCSS あと個別に対策したくなるほど頻繁に表示されるのでしょうか？ 私はこれを入れておらず、Chromeで拡張機能の AdBlock を入れている(YouTubeサイトは広告を許可しないと見れなくなったので広告は許可しています)からかもしれませんが、広告動画は表示されますがPremium勧誘はほとんど表示されない感じですが。

質問を書き換えたようですが、最初からそのように書いてほしかったです。質問者さんが質問を書く時間と労力を削減したつもりかもしれませんが、質問を見て考えてくれた閲覧者・回答者の時間と労力を無駄にしているという認識はありますか？

結局自分で最初に書いた通りMutationObserverを使うしかないという結論に至ったのでそれを用いて以下のスクリプトを書きました。
Remove YouTube Premium promotion pop-up - greasyfork

既存のルールを無理に書き換えなくても
.ytd-popup-container !important {
  display: none;
}

というスタイルを挿入してやれば、変更されます。これは一例ですが、厳密には既存のルール定義に対して、詳細度が上回るような定義をするだけです。

一時期タイトルがuserscriptになっていましたが、もっと本質的にはuser cssで実現できる気がします。何にせよ、実現方法は質問者さんの好みで選べばいいかなと。

言われてしまえば簡単な話でしたが以下の回答と同じ感じでしょうか https://stackoverflow.com/a/62069454/3809427

どうしても既存のルールセットを動的に変更したいなら、document.styleSheets を利用する方法しかないと思われます。
オリジンの異なるスタイルシートの場合は、cssRulesプロパティなどが利用できないので既存のルールセットの書き換えは不可能です。その場合は、同一オリジンのスタイルシートを用意しておき、変更したい内容で上書きするようなルールセットを insertRule() で追加するなりすればよいでしょう。

以下のページと同じエラーが起き、回答も見ましたが簡単には解決できないようです https://stackoverflow.com/q/49101179/3809427

同一オリジンならinsertRule()できるはずですよ。ローカルファイルだとすべて別オリジンになります。

申し訳ありません、質問文に入れ忘れてましたがuserscriptの話なので多分その「ローカルファイル」に当たります。
